# laravel livewire click event does not fire in other component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I created the livewire component, that contains two includes

```
@include('components.header')
@include('components.body')
```

In my **header.blade.php**, the `increment` function is working fine and can fire the event.

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>{{ $counter }}</h1>
    <button wire:click="increment">temp</button>
</div>
```

But in my **body.blade.php**, the `increment` function does not fire the event, but can show the `$counter` value.

```
<div id="body">
    <h1>{{ $counter }}</h1>
    <button wire:click="increment">temp</button>
</div>
```

---

But If I will switch the order, the **body** `click` event can fire while the **header** won't

```
@include('components.body')
@include('components.header')
```

Comment: Is this your full Livewire blade view? As a Livewire blade can only have a singular root element, and this would cause it to have 2

Comment: @Yinci yes. i have not proceeded yet to more complex, since I'm stuck at this.

Comment: Post your whole Livewire/whatever.blade.php that includes these... idealy also your App\Models\Livewire\Class.php

Answer (score 0):

As Livewire only can have one root element, simply wrapping it in a `div` will solve your issue.

```html
<div>
    @include('components.body')
    @include('components.header')
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that one actually, earlier i did my research. but won't work.

Comment: Perhaps share the code of your component because this should work.

Comment: those exactly the code in my two components, (did not proceed yet to actual design). I tried testing if I can do like `context` or `redux` in Reactjs. But unfortunately did not work.

Comment: I meant your Livewire component, not the blade view(s). I have literally copied everything over into a fresh Livewire component and it works just fine, and if there's only one root, then your component will have the culprit.